# Quick (pre-loading?) thumbnail slideshow with multiple image files per slide

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

1. How do I create a HTML-based slideshow which shows multiple images (thumbnails) per slide?
2. How do I make sure the next slide (i.e., the next group of thumbnails) is shown as quickly as possible when I want to advance? (E.g. preloading of all the images or similar, maybe multiple slides in advance)
3. How can I implement functionality so that clicking on a thumbnail shows a large picture on top of the slideshow, and have this large picture also switches back/forth when I browse the slides?

---

Some  background:

I am performing a multi-instrument case study, which means I have a folder with LOTS of images showing data from a given instrument at a certain date/time (see the image). I would like to show all images from a single date/time in a grid as a single "slide" in an HTML slideshow, and furthermore be able to quickly scroll through the slides (the groups of images) using the arrow keys. I aim to do this locally on my computer (local image and html files).

I have previously plotted everything at once and saved all the different plots as a single file (exemplified by the picture above), which unfortunately means that everything will have to be re-plotted (taking 10-20 hours to run when plotting 7 hours of data) every time I need to change anything in just one of the plots. This is not desirable in the long run (and it will indeed be a very long run if I don't do anything). That's why I want to save all the small plots separately and show them as described above.

[image: I would like a single slide to look like this.]

Comment: This looks for me like you're asking us to do your work?

Comment: @ReeCube Sorry, maybe I phrased it badly. I'm wondering how I myself can go about doing this. I don't need a complete working example, just some pointers in the right directions. Was there anything in particular in my question that gave off the impression that I want others to do the work for me? Question 3, perhaps? I ask so I can edit it to better clarify my meaning.

Comment: Try to ask specific questions and not general questions like this

Comment: For your problem: if you want to use a plugin, you will find one on google (I'm pretty sure) and if you want to write your own solution, create a 3-dimensional div hirarchie: a top-level-container with a fixed size and overflow hidden and a scroll child, with the width of 100% * the count of slide pages (do this in javascript) and then a container for each page (width 100%, float left, display inline-block) containing your images inside (or other content as you want)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback regarding my question, I have now rephrased and reordered to make my questions more concrete and stand on their own without any background.

Comment: Regarding your solution, I think I see what you mean. If I understand correctly, this would make a scrolling page. Unfortunately I need to show/update the images in the exact same place to easily see what has changed from minute to minute for each picture. I'm afraid scrolling is not a viable option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63865/discussion-between-cmeeren-and-reecube).